# php mysqli Unique first character is not coming properly

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get the data from a table based on the value from another table.
But it is showing the characters multiple times.

From `articles` table im getting the DISTINCT `mem_id`'s because i do not want to show the users which has not posted any article.

**Note: both tables are from different databases.**

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($dba, "SELECT DISTINCT mem_id from articles
WHERE status = 1
");
while ($QR1 =   mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
    
$query2 = mysqli_query($dbf, "SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(mem_name, 1) mem_name from mem_user
WHERE mem_id in ('".$QR1['mem_id']."')
and article = 1 and status = 1
");
$char_rows  =   mysqli_num_rows($query2);
$chars  =   mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
$char = strtoupper(substr($chars['mem_name'], 0, 1));

echo '<a class="btn btn-xs loadAlphabet" name="'.$char_rows.'" 
value="'.$char.'"
id="'.$char.'"
style="border: 1px solid #ddd; margin-bottom: 5px;">'.$char.'</a>'. "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use only on req, with a join statement ?

Something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(mu.mem_name, 1) mem_name
FROM Db1.article a
JOIN Db2.mem_user mu ON mu.mem_id = a.mem_id
WHERE mu.article = 1 and mu.status = 1 and a.status = 1
```

Comment: both tables are from 2 different databases

Comment: @usman610 Sorry, I just edited my post about that.
You can specify database name before table name, separated by a dot.
Unless they are on different servers ?

Comment: would you please make a full query i mean with connection and usage ass above? because with this it is showing the users which never posted any article

Comment: Can you demonstrate your problem with some data on a site like this one please ? https://www.db-fiddle.com/